# After reloading function from file Python still uses the old version

Tags: python, python-import

I created the following `file.py`

```
def function():
  print('Hello')
```

I import and call this function:

```
>>> from file import function
>>> function
<function function at 0x0000022BF425FB70>
>>> function()
Hello
```

Now I changed function to print "Hello world" instead of "Hello" and reload file again:

```
>>> from file import function
>>> function
<function function at 0x0000022BF425FB70>
>>> function()
Hello
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getsource(function)
"def function():\n\tprint('Hello world')\n"
```

What confuses me is that the new function is actually reloaded (which we can see from function's source code in the last line) but it still prints "Hello". How is it possible? Also function pointer didn't change even if the source code of the function did.

**Edit:**
I think it is not duplicate with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module) question. I'm not asking how to reload function. I'm asking how come that source code is changed after reloading and Python still calls old version of the function.

Comment: Once you import it, it's always going to be the version you imported, even if you change it afterwards. You can use the `reload` function in the `importlib` library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)

Comment: @iamchoosinganame But the source code is changed, it is not now the same function.

Comment: That's true, but it's not how python works. Once you have imported a module you can only import the new version using ```importlib.reload`` Someone else may be able to explain the reasoning behind this. You can also start a new python session and  then when you import you will get the new version.

Comment: @rdas I edited the question trying to explain that it is not a duplicated question.

Comment: `inspect.getsource()` looks at the file on disk, whether or not that version of the file on disk gave rise to the function currently in memory.  Notice that the `function` object shows an id of 0x0000022BF425FB70 both before and after - that's not conclusive proof (ids can be reused for objects with disjoint lifetimes), but it's evidence that you didn't actually reload anything.

Comment: @Petar I think it's already been explained in the comments why this is happening and the underlying cause is explained in the question marked as duplicate.

Comment: @hasonharper That's the answer to my question I was looking for. You can move it from comments to answer if you want.